# How can I use Regex to find if I used the same character in multiple different locations?

Tags: regex

So I am looking through different numbers that have different delimiters, and I want to find all numbers that have the same delimiter.

Basically, I want the following

```
123+456+7890 // MATCH
123-456-7890 // MATCH
123.456.7890 // MATCH
123+456-7890 // FAILURE
```

My current regex I plan to use was

```
\d{3}[+-.]\d{3}[+-.]\d{4}
```

However, it would match number sequences that have the different delimiters. I don't want to use one big huge OR for something like this because the real life equivalent has many more characters that could fit there.

Is there a way to match the same character in multiple locations?

Comment: I came back much later and found both answers. Looking at both answers being very similar, I accepted the answer that I believe better explained the Regex in place. anubhava's answer mentions that I can use a capture group and a back-reference, where as @degant actually explains how the regex works. If someone else comes along and finds this question/answer, I think that Degant's would be more helpful than anubhava.

Also, it shouldn't matter who answers first, it should only matter which answer is the best.

Comment: @anubhava The very first unedited answer still had better bullet points and was absolutely still correct. Are you arguing with my decision because you want the reputation? This discussion is not constructive to the question/answer at all.

Comment: @anubhava I would like to point out that I did read the bullet points on both answers before choosing an answer. I chose the answer that had better bullet points.

Comment: No sir, as an OP you are best judge to decide the acceptance. I am merely arguing the case that you didn't find any explanation of regex in my answer.

Comment: Also you can see in the first update in degant 's edit history that regex `\d{3}([+-.])\d{3}\1\d{4}` was also matching commas as in `123,456,7890` (it was corrected later on since I had the correct answer already posted). Even now it is not entirely correct without anchors on either side.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a back reference like this:

```
\d{3}([+.-])\d{3}\1\d{4}
```

- The first operator that is matched `[+-.]` is kept inside a capturing group so that it can be referenced later.
- `\1` is a backreference to the first capturing group which in this case is `[+-.]` so it will ensure that the operator is same as the previous one.

[Regex 101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/mQJeXx/1)

You can read more about backreferences [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html)

Answer (score 7):

You can use a captured group and a back-reference to ensure same delimiter is used again.

```
^\d{3}([+.-])\d{3}\1\d{4}$
```

- `([+.-])` here we capture delimiter in group #1
- `\1` Here we are using back-reference of same delimiter

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wkjGnT/1)